# How will illegal utf-8 byte sequence been parsed?

Tags: utf-8

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8.

```
11011111 11111111
```

is an illegal utf-8 byte sequence.

How will it been parsed?

and

How does `vim`, `iconv`, `java`... deal with illegal utf-8 byte sequence?

Comment: That depends on the application, obviously. There may be an official guide on what an app *should* do, but what it *will* do varies widely.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is a *transformation format* to derive a subset of the Universal Character Set (UCS). This transformation and decoding of such characters is governed by rules defined as Internet Standards.

In section 3 of [RFC3629](http://rfc3629.openrfc.org/), it clearly says:

> Implementations of the decoding algorithm above MUST protect against
>   decoding invalid sequences.

It has no specific instructions on how to handle such invalid sequences other that "protect against", it depends on the nature of implementation and implementers what specific actions will be taken.